# AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper - "Duplicate Java type found!"

Tags: azure, facebook-graph-api, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, onedrive

I'm developing an application with Xamarin.Forms, where the application should run on Windows and Android for the first version.
It should the Graph API to access OneDrive/OneNote.

I already managed to retrieve the name of the logged-in user under UWP (Universal Windows Platform).
So I tried to deploy the same app to Android, where the calls are quite similar with the following extensions:

- UIParent is necessary
- AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data); call is necessary

The UIParent part already works, but the AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper cannot be built into the app.

Here Visual Studio says:

```
Duplicate Java type found!
Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique.
First Type:
'Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Android.SystemWebview.AuthenticationActivity, Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=2.6.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae';
Second Type:
'Microsoft.Identity.Core.UI.SystemWebview.AuthenticationActivity, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

The Xamarin application is started as new app using the ".NET Standard" code sharing strategy with blank template from Visual Studio. As I read this has superseded the "PCL" way, which cannot be selected in VS2017.

Do you have an idea how this could be resolved?

Comment: Did you use Xamarin.Auth and MobileServices at the same time? What are the nuget versions? Clean the solution (and manually delete the obj directory contents if needed) and try a rebuild

Answer (score 1):

This error started because the MSAL repo was sharing code with ADAL while the team worked to bring feature parity to MSAL and a common cache. Then, MSAL was moved back to its original repo, but the Android and iOS namespaces were not updated, so there was a conflict if using both ADAL and MSAL in the same project. 
This has been fixed in [MSAL 2.7](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/releases/tag/2.7.0) for the iOS ViewController classes and [ADAL 4.5](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/releases/tag/ADAL-v4.5.0) for the Android AuthenticationActivity classes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need both Microsoft.Identity.Client (MSAL) and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (ADAL) packages?

MSAL is used to authenticate against the AAD v2 endpoint, whereas ADAL is used to authenticate against the AAD v1 endpoint, so in theory you'd need either one or the other.

Maybe there are cases where you'd need both, but I was getting the same error and as I was using MSAL to authenticate I uninstalled the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory nuget package and all was well.